# Spring JPA stop relationships creating new tables

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entity, relationship

I am trying to create some relationships and when I have done it is creating new tables, how can I stop this happening.
Here is my parent class.

```
@Entity
public class Seasons {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int Season_Id;
private String season;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "season")
private List<Fixture> fixtures;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "season")
private List<Referee> referee;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "season")
private List<Team> team;
}
```

And here is an example of one of the 3 classes I am trying to create a relationship between. This one is the fixture class.

```
@Entity
public class Fixture {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int fixture_Id;
@OneToOne
private FixtureStats stats;
@OneToOne
private Referee referee;
@OneToOne
private Team  Home;
@OneToOne
private Team Away;
private int week;
@ManyToOne
private Seasons season;
}
```

When I run the program these are the tables that are created:

- seasons
- seasons.referees
- seasons.fixtures
- seasons.teams

I would rather not have to have the @ManyToOne private Season season; in the child classes but if it is needed I'll have to live with it. I have tried searching for this but can't find anything on the topic.

**Update:**
I have now used @JoinColumn, however this only provides a column for fixtures for some reason?
Here is the updated code

```
@Entity
public class Seasons {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int Season_Id;
private String season;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn
private List<Fixture> fixtures;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn
private List<Referee> referee;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn
private List<Team> team;
```

Cheers

Comment: Just use `@JoinColumn` with `@OneToMany` and remove `mappedBy`

Comment: Thank you I've done this but only fixtures is getting a column in my table, do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I understand that you also removed the `@ManyToOne` side of the associations? If so, it should work out of the box. What happens when you try to insert data, does it complain about a missing column?

Comment: I don't get an error or anything, the data just isn't saving. And yeah I removed the many to one side.